# Could a powerful nearly omniscient magic AI God prevent humans from destroying themselves?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, balancing-magic-systems

From an outsider's perspective this world looks like your typical fantasy realm with feudalism, mages and fantastic creatures. Only few entities know, that this world used to be a backwater colony of a human galactic superpower.

Many centuries (millenias?) ago mankind was an interstellar civilization. At some point humanity learned how to "edit" the fabric of reality by manipulating the laws of physics. Technology became indistinguishable from magic. Since then every populated planet had a World Engine installed - a powerful AI, that could literally change reality in any way possible.

Every citizen of the galaxy had an access to the World Engines through special telepathic interface. By inputting specific commands, people could edit their surroundings to their likings. *Reality could be whatever they want*. Picture a full Infinity Gauntlet but without lethal consequences - and restricted to a single planet.

The golden age of humanity didn't last long. At some moment most of the galaxy was destroyed as a result of some terrible technological disaster. The catastrophe erased every human colony in the galaxy... Except one planet.

The survivors were utterly shocked by the destruction of the civilization. Together they modified the last World Engine's programming, giving it a set of directives:

1. AI can't let human society destroy itself.
2. AI can't let humans enter space age.
3. AI can't let humans modify the AI's core programming.
4. AI can't edit reality on its own volition, only by request of its
   users.
5. Any attempts of scientific research that lead to risk of violating
   Directives #1, #2 and #3 must be stopped immediately, by permanently
   banning violators from using the Interface. (Read: heretics, who try
   to defy the God, are to be excommunicated forever - as the Church
   would interpret this rule later).

The ancestors of this quasi-fantasy world were terrified that surviving humans could destroy themselves once again. So they did their best to ensure that their descendants would live in a stagnant world that will exist forever. Since then the World Engine, which would later become an object of religious worship, began its eternal watch, conducting 24/7 surveillance of the world - both physical and telepathic.

The only way the WE can control humans is by restricting Interface access from "dangerous" individuals. And, unless some "spell" might potentially lead to the violation of Directives, the AI executes commands without questions - even if an individual uses the Interface to hurt others.

Since there are countless ways of misusing the "magic", here are the most obvious restrictions that AI should impose:

- Telekinesis: can't accelerate objects beyond certain speed (at
  relativistic speeds any object turns into a nuke).
- Gravity/mass manipulation: can't increase an object's mass to the point it gains its own gravity.
- Can't split atoms or perform any subatomic manipulations.
- AoE "spells" range and magnitude are restricted, thus it's impossible to, say, burn/freeze/delete an entire region.
- Explosion "spells" energy input restricted. In other words no nuke
  equivalents.
- No time travel or retroactive reality editing.
- Can't create and manipulate anti-matter.

Additionally, the Interface access is granted only to those, who have successfully passed special training and tests. Not just anyone gets to become a "mage". Individuals, deemed by the AI as mentally ill, are automatically banned from the system, until they recover. The same goes for intoxicated people.

*I wonder, are the abovementioned restrictions sufficient enough to prevent people from accidentally/intentionally destroying their civilization? And is it possible for the "mages" to cheat or bypass the system somehow and break the directives indirectly without triggering AI's alarm system?*

Comment: Modifying Point 4 seems like a loophole. It's not core programming (it was added on).

Comment: Too many undefined variables to be able to assess, just looking at a couple:  "society" + "destroy" and "space age".  If the society at the time of initial conditions is patriarchal and the people start moving towards either a matriarchal or gender-equal society - is the AI going to force everyone to remain patriarchal because otherwise they are "destroying" the "society"?  Does "space age" mean all post 1950's tech or are humans allowed to have an internet and smart phones just no big rockets?

Comment: A couple of addenda. 
The AI strives to preserve humanity as a species. If there is a revolution or some significant societal change in this world (but mankind still lives), then the WE doesn't care.
The space age means the ability to build and launch spacecrafts. If denizens of this world create some kind of IT equivalents, then, again, the AI probably won't intervene.

Comment: very reminiscent of qntm's  https://qntm.org/ra

Comment: @ths from the potential perspective of any uneducated masses among its population it could also end up feeling a little like Pratchett's original sci fi Disc World 'Strata' ..  .. aside from it not actually being flat of course  'spells' in that were actually the governing computer responding to verbal 'command phrases'.

Comment: It seems like you're asking about the actions and capabilities. Such questions are by definition not about worldbuilding, and aren't suitable for this site.

Comment: This reads fairly like a how do I beat an invincible opponent prompt, which is forbidden.

Comment: VTC: (a) The [help/dont-ask] specifically states to not give us your answers and then ask for more answers. You have a working system and are only brainstorming for more input, "in case I missed something." That's not our job. This is not a specific problem to be solved (see [help/on-topic]). (b) Earlier you said the reprogrammers had changed the code so that no human could ever again change the code. That's a great basis for unintended consequences... (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... But it also answers your own question admirably. In fact, given the list of directives you've provided, your statement that instructions are carried out immediately even if it hurts other people is *contradictory* as the AI could only do so based on the directives if it could *guarantee* that such harm wouldn't violate the directives... which would be truly omniscient. (c) Asking how people can break or bypass your godlike creature ("how to defeat my godlike character" is a poor question as the answer is always, "with a weakness, what is it?") is asking us... (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... to write your story, which is specifically contrary to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 7):

Yes, very easily.
The most effective way to abide by all its directives **is for the AI to destroy humanity itself**. And then possibly itself.

- Humanity won't destroy itself.
- Humans won't enter space age.
- Humans won't modify the AI's core programming.
- AI won't be able to edit reality.
- This will immediately put a halt to "*any attempts of scientific research leading to risk of violating Directives #1, #2 and #3*".

Comment: But then, wouldn't that contradict the Directive #1 by allowing humanity to destroy itself through creating and programming the AI in the first place?

Comment: @Magma It would, but necessarily so, as the AI could not have prevented something it necessarily postdates. It's actually an additional reason to destroy humanity immediately.

Answer (score 4):

### Loopholes

1. Get the AI to create another AI;
2. Get the AI to develop a system that nullifies or destroys the AI;
3. Get the AI to send a few people to a new world out of the AI's jurisdiction without them knowing how (thus evading point 2);
4. Redefine 'human', 'space age', 'reality', etc.
5. Modify Point 4. It's not core programming (it was added on).

Answer (score 3):

These rules remind me of Asimov's rules of robotics. There was no omniscience there, though. If you use the word nearly, it means that mistakes are possible. In addition there is a difference between omniscience and omnipotent. Systems could break, and the ai can know about it. But still be unable to fix them in time. So humanity could destroy itself.

Answer (score 2):

In many holy books, starting from the Bible, humans manage to screw up even though they are supervised by a truly omnipotent and omniscient deity. And, as the saying goes, "*against stupidity the very gods themselves contend in vain*"

It is very likely that somebody will rise against this controlling force, because why should we be constrained and limited in our doing and so on, and from there on the society could become more and more polarized and divided. It has happened and it is still happening in our history.

Answer (score 1):

Easy pie. Just rob people of free will. Your AI needs to insert some kind of mind-reading, mind-controlling device into head of every human being, and then give them commands to do such and such things. Whole humanity will be turned into puppets of the AI and thus the AI will be able to easily keep its directives.

Answer (score 1):

**Doesn't Work.**

You having a "living god" AI Cube that can do almost anything. You are not asking what the cube should do. You are asking if THIS set of rules will work. I don't think they will.

According to your rules, the AI Cube will perform some spells if the adherents obey the commands to not develop technology. Naturally the Church that controls the Cube becomes one of the most powerful factions in the world. Once the Church gets powerful enough it will gain enemies.

These enemies do not have access to the Cube because they are not allowed. So they develop technology -- after all why not -- and bomb the Church to bits. The Church cannot stop them because the AI has limits on how powerful the spells are.

A better plan is for your godlike AI to simply change the laws of physics so technology cannot be invented. For example there is little copper, iron, or gold on the planet; no hydrocarbons for fuel; or electricity behaves differently and cannot be used to circuits. Then they are stuck in the medieval age forever.